# DRY type annotation for QuickCheck properties

Tags: haskell-stack, quickcheck

With QuickCheck, one can write parametrically polymorphic properties, like this:

```
associativityLaw :: (Eq a, Show a, Semigroup a) => a -> a -> a -> Property
associativityLaw x y z = (x <> y) <> z === x <> (y <> z)
```

This is just an example, as my actual properties are more complex, but it illustrates the problem well enough. This property verifies that for a type `a`, the `<>` operator is associative.

Imagine that I'd like to exercise this property for more than one type. I could define my test list like this:

```
tests =
  [
    testGroup "Monoid laws" [
      testProperty "Associativity law, [Int]" (associativityLaw :: [Int] -> [Int] -> [Int] -> Property),
      testProperty "Associativity law, Sum Int" (associativityLaw :: Sum Int -> Sum Int -> Sum Int -> Property)
    ]
  ]
```

This works, but feels unnecessarily verbose. I'd like to be able to simply state that for a given property, `a` should be `[Int]`, or `a` should be `Sum Int`.

Something like this **hypothetical** syntax:

```
testProperty "Associativity law, [Int]" (associativityLaw :: a = [Int]),
testProperty "Associativity law, Sum Int" (associativityLaw :: a = Sum Int)
```

Is there a way to do this, perhaps with a GHC language extension?

My actual problem involves higher-kinded types, and I'd like to be able to state that e.g. `f a` is `[Int]`, or `f a` is `Maybe String`.

I'm aware of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26430859/126014), but both options (`Proxy` and `Tagged`) seem, as described there, at least, too awkward to really address the issue.

Comment: I think I would rather be explicit and specify the *generator* instead of the *default arbitrary type*. I've made a Gist with an example [here](https://gist.github.com/moodmosaic/7fa1f4424383d188e53b4586d167d1a9). Of course, it's in Hedgehog but may be portable to QC. /cc @dcastro

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `TypeApplications` to bind type variables like this:

```
{-# LANGUAGE TypeApplications #-}

associativityLaw @[Int]
```

In the case you mentioned where you have a higher kinded type and you want to bind `f a` to `[Int]`, you have to bind the type variables `f` and `a` separately:

```
fmap @[] @Int
```

For functions with more than one type variable, you can apply the args in order:

```
f :: a -> b -> Int

-- bind both type vars    
f @Int @String

-- bind just the first type var, and let GHC infer the second one
f @Int

-- bind just the second type var, and let GHC infer the first one
f @_ @String
```

Sometimes the "order" of the type variables may not be obvious, but you can use `:type +v` and ask GHCi for more info:

```
λ> :t +v traverse
traverse
  :: Traversable t =>
     forall (f :: * -> *) a b.
     Applicative f =>
     (a -> f b) -> t a -> f (t b)
```

In standard haskell, the "order" of the type variables doesn't matter, so GHC just makes one up for you. But in the presence of `TypeApplications`, the order *does* matter:

```
map :: forall b a. (a -> b) -> ([a] -> [b])
-- is not the same as
map :: forall a b. (a -> b) -> ([a] -> [b])
```

For this reason, when working with highly parametric code, or you expect your users are going to want to use `TypeApplications` on your functions, you might want to explicitly set the order of your type vars instead of letting GHC define an order for you, with `ExplicitForAll`:

```
{-# LANGUAGE ExplicitForAll #-}

map :: forall a b. (a -> b) -> ([a] -> [b])
```

Which feels a lot like `<T1, T2>` in java or c#